# How to check for null in this specific situation

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

For a dynamic menu with 4 (1,2,3,D) levels in (x amount of) missions. I have a Typer script on a text that activates when the player clicks a button but when he clicks the next button: the next Typer writes the text over the other one because both Texts are (and need to be) in the same place.

there are other solutions like using public gameobjects + SetActive but i will have a lot of buttons so this would be inconvenient so instead:

i would make a function that disables all found texts for that mission before enabling the new one but TextLevel3 will sometimes simply not exist and return null(referenceExeption) so i want to check for this and break if its null or continue if it's safe to. I'm just not sure how to do this with combined with the Gameobject.Find and GetComponent

```
    void DisableTexts()
     {
     text = GameObject.Find("TextLevel1").GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;
     text = GameObject.Find("TextLevel2").GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;
     text = GameObject.Find("TextLevelD").GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;

     //This is what i need: 
       Check if (TextLevel3 != null){go ahead} or if (TextLevel3 = null){break;(?)}

     text = GameObject.Find("TextLevel3").GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;
     }

     public void CheckLevel (string selectedLevel)
 {
     DisableTexts();
 GameObject.Find("TextLevel" + selectedLevel).GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = true;
 CurrentMission = "Level" + missionSelected + "." + selectedLevel;    
 }
```

Comment: `var t= GameObject.Find("TextLevel3"); if(t!=null)  text=t...`

Answer (score 0):

first you should check if it exist and then use `GetComponent` otherwise you will get  a`null exception`

```
if(GameObject.Find("TextLevel3") != null )
      text = GameObject.Find("TextLevel3").GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Once C# 6 is released, you can use the ?. operator for this, so this would become:

`text = GameObject.Find("TextLevel3")?.GetComponent<Typer>().enabled = false;`

However, C# 6 wont be here untill VS2015 is released.